# A fast way to calculate crossing in a graph of lines

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, optimization, graph

I have a graph of 3119 lines, each line input is line (x,y)

I need to calculate crossing number (number of intersection) "CRS"

Whatever the method of intersection calculating is, I know there are a lot of efficient and fast ones

but every time I have to do a 4,865,640 step, [n * (n-1) / 2]

```
CRS = 0
For i = 0 To graph.Count - 2
    For j = i + 1 To graph.Count - 1
        Dim li = graph(i)
        Dim l = graph(j)
        If line_intersect(li, l) Then CRS = CRS + 1
    Next
Next
```

Is there any fast method to calculate this crossing number, as each trial consumes a lot of time as I have to change the y values of a group of lines and recalculating CRS for optimization

Comment: Are you computing the actual intersections or really just the number? Are we really talking about lines or about line segments? If you consider only lines and only the number it should be easy as every non-parallel line pair intersects.

Comment: If you want to do it by yourself, then this is a math problem.
To optimize intersections computation and avoid computing every possible combinations, you have no choice but divide your space:
If you have N lines, the number of possible combinations is indeed n*(n-1)/2.
But if you divide your space into k sub-spaces you have will have less combination in each space.
If I consider your problem, the best number of sub-spaces is 1.5 ... so I would suggest to use 2 instead.